# How do I update libcurl to 7.21.7 when I've updated the command line curl OSX?

Tags: macos, curl, libcurl

I've built curl and copied the binary and /.libs over to /usr/bin. The command now gives:

```
curl 7.21.7 (x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0) libcurl/7.21.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8k zlib/1.2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
```

Yet curl_version() gives:

```
libcurl/7.19.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.3
```

How do I update libcurl as well on OSX 10.6.8?

Thank you.

I also have these files under /usr/bin:

```
/usr/lib/libcurl.2.dylib
/usr/lib/libcurl.3.dylib
/usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
/usr/lib/libcurl.dylib
```

Do I have to compile another one of these? I don't know how, with what, where. I also have these:

```
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/lib/libcurl.2.dylib
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/lib/libcurl.3.dylib
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/lib/libcurl.4.0.0.dylib
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/lib/libcurl.dylib
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/lib/libcurl.2.dylib
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/lib/libcurl.3.dylib
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/lib/libcurl.dylib
```

Comment: did you copied the binaries or did you slink them ?

Comment: I used mv to put them into /usr/bin. It doesn't make any sense. People act that libcurl somehow depends on the installed command curl yet it doesn't match.

Comment: how do you build? autoconf/automake? did you reconfigure your build after the new package install?

Comment: I ran make which appeared to work.

Comment: I used "MacOSX-Framework" to make a framework. I tried it out but I don't know how to include it. Can you include frameworks into C? I'm soooo confused.

Comment: You should *never* modify or delete files in `/usr/bin`.  They are supplied by Apple as part of OS X.  You run the risk of breaking functionality in your system and your changes can be silently removed by any Apple Software Update to OS X.  If you want to install another version of a program found in `/usr/bin`, install it to `/usr/local/bin` (or some other directory) and modify your shell path so that `/usr/local/bin` comes before `/usr/bin`.  Or use an alias or the absolute path.  But don't overwrite things anywhere in `/usr` other than `/usr/local`.

Comment: Considering I had to reinstall Snow Leopard, I think I learned my lesson! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it I used the commands I finally found in an installation manual on the internet:

./configure
make
sudo make install

THen I moved the dylib to the dylib location linked to by my program. Shame the dylib compiled is in i386 and not x86-64 but it works.